# Developing ever first authentication application on Laravel with .blade files

Tags: laravel, authentication, controller, laravel-blade

so I decided to learn Laravel. I've built some small applications, but now, I decided to build a small CMS on my own and I am facing an issue in pretty much the beginning. I created an AuthController, created routes and created a login form with .blade.php

Now, when I try to log in, I have an error: The provided credentials do not match our records! (Error of course created by my own)

I don't know if I missed something or something is written incorrectly, but I just can't log in.

These are my codes:

web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Login
Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login.form');
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login.submit');

// Logout
Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

AuthController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);

        $remember = $request->has('remember');

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended('/'); // Redirects to home page after log in
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records!'
        ])->onlyInput('email');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        Auth::logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

login.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.auth')

@section('content')
    <div class="">
        <a class="">
            PI Blog
        </a>
        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
        <div class="">
            <div class="p-6 space-y-4 md:space-y-6 sm:p-8">
                <h1 class="">
                    Sign in to your account
                </h1>
                <form class="" action="{{ route('login.submit') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <div>
                        <label for="email" class="">Your email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="" placeholder="name@domain.com" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="password" class="">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="••••••••" class="" required="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="">
                              <input id="remember" aria-describedby="remember" type="checkbox" class="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
                              <label for="remember" class="">Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="">Forgot password?</a>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="">Sign in</button>
                    <p class="">
                        Don’t have an account yet? <a href="#" class="">Sign up</a>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

2023_10_22_192933_create_users_table.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('role_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

I'VE REMOVED ALL OF THE TAILWIND CLASSES IN BLADE JUST FOR A BETTER READABILITY! ALL CLASSES ARE JUST TAILWIND CLASSES!

Am I missing something here? If anything, I have generated a password with bcrypt('password') and added it to my database manually without any seeding and this is how my user basically looks in the DB:

```
id: 1
role_id: 1
username: user
email: user@gmail.com
email_verified_at: 2023-10-24 21:07:05
password: $2y$10$RKa.O9wZSchX9XUgGr0O6OlDI49Tsv2T7JQDTN96/de7sKLsB0AbG
remember_token: NULL
created_at: 2023-10-24 21:05:05
updated_at: 2023-10-24 21:05:05
```

And when I am logging in - I provide the email and the password I used in bcrypt('password') command (tried both with and without quotes if anything)

I would appreciate any kind of help as I am eager to learn, but faced an issue basically in the very beginning

Basically, tried creating a user in DB manually and logging in to that account, but face the error "The provided credentials do not match our records!" that I created myself.

Of course, built the project just in case as well (I don't know if that is necessary, but did it just in case)

Comment: Okay, I solved it on my own. So the reason I was facing this issue was because Auth class and Tinker is using some kind of different hashing.

So when I ran bcrypt('password') in Tinker that hash was different from the one I decided to add in my Controller: 
        Log::info("Entered email: " . $request->email);
        Log::info("Entered password: " . $request->password);
        Log::info("Hashed version of entered password: " . bcrypt($request->password));

The tinker's bcrypt and bcrypt($request->password) returned different hashes, so I just updated the password in database.

Comment: Hash is always different. Any time function is used, it returns different string. Do not rely on some string you got from terminal. Something else is in matter. 
Other than that, why don't you use inbuilt Laravel method for authentication - you will get rid of lot of work but also will have secure and tested module (i.e. authentication module). Check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication).

Comment: Yeah, thanks for advise. I just basically try to do everything on my own without any packages so I could understand Laravel as best as possible. Since I've just started digging into it I don't want to use any packages or something like that. So I try to code as much as possible on my own and hope to write a decent code:) And from there on, once I understand everything a bit more in depth - I will use some packages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Good job then. I'd like to add whether you use the database, tinker, or php's password_hash to bcrypt the password, make sure the rounds attribute is the same for all the parts of your dataflow, because each round outputs a different hash. For the framework, see config/hashing.php.